# JSON unmarshal integer field into a string

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I am struggling with deserializing a integer into a string struct field.
The struct field is a string and is expected to be assignable from users of my library. That's why I want it to be a string, since for the purpose of writing it to the database I actually don't care about the value inside.
The users can supply text, but some just assign integers.

Consider this struct:

```
type Test struct {
  Foo string
}
```

Sometimes I end up with a JSON value that is valid but won't deserialize into the struct due to the Foo field being a integer instead of a string:

```
{ "foo": "1" } // works
{ "foo": 1 } // doesn't
```

json.Unmarshal will blow up with the following error:
`json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field test.Foo of type string`

See the reproduction: https://play.golang.org/p/4Qau3umaVm

Now in every other JSON library (in other languages) I have worked in so far, if the target field is a string and you get a integer the deserializer will usually just wrap the int in a string and be done with it. Can this be achieved in Go?

Since I can't really control how the data comes in I need to make `json.Unmarshal` unsensitive to this - the other solution would be to define Foo as `interface{}` which needlessly complicates my code with type assertions etc..

Any ideas on how to do this? I basically need the inverse of `json:",string"`

Comment: You could implement the [json.Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To handle big structs you can use embedding.

Updated to not discard possibly previously set field values.

```
func (t *T) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    type T2 T // create new type with same structure as T but without its method set!
    x := struct{
        T2 // embed
        Foo json.Number `json:"foo"`
    }{T2: T2(*t)} // don't forget this, if you do and 't' already has some fields set you would lose them

    if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &x); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *t = T(x.T2)
    t.Foo = x.Foo.String()
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BytXCeHMvt

Comment: Good example (but that's not an [alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations))

Comment: I know it's not the 1.9 alias, but wasn't this called aliasing before?

Comment: Nope, it's never been called an alias because it creates a new type. Doesn't mean others haven't called it an "alias" in the past, but I've been doing my best to be pedantic on the matter for years, especially once the real alias idea was brought up ;) The only _real_ aliases previously were `byte` and `rune`, for `uint8` and `int32` respectively.

Comment: Ah yes, I think it's because of `rune` and friends that I was calling every `type T2 T1` an alias. Anyway thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. Thanks so much! I'll have to read up on embedding.

Comment: Love the way you get around a recursive `Unmarshal`. It's a better hack than what I came up with trying to `Unmarshal` the same struct in the `UnmarshalJSON` implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You can customize how the data structure is Unmarshaler by implementing the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface.

The simplest way to handle unknown types is to unnmarshal the JSON into an intermediate structure, and handle the type assertions and validation during deserialization:

```
type test struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
}

func (t *test) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    tmp := struct {
        Foo interface{} `json:"foo"`
    }{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &tmp); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    switch v := tmp.Foo.(type) {
    case float64:
        t.Foo = strconv.Itoa(int(v))
    case string:
        t.Foo = v
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid value for Foo: %v", v)
    }

    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/t0eI4wCxdB

Comment: Thanks - I also thought about that. But this is a really big struct.. Is there a way how I can implement the unmarshaler only for the problematic field?

Answer (score 0):

I got a rather simple solution in case you don't know what type to expect.
You always end up with a string.

```golang
type String string

func (s *String) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    d = bytes.Trim(d, `"`) // get rid of string quotes
    *s = String(d)
    return nil
}
```

Working example:
https://go.dev/play/p/XFLgtx6s4N1