# Sending ByteArray from Kotlin to byte[] in Golang

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

In Android, we're having an image of ByteArray which is supposed to be send to the backend which is written in Go.

The problem here is that, Kotlin's ByteArray is signed, while Go's byte[] is unsigned. And because of this, while sending the ByteArray from Kotlin (Android) to Go (Backend), I'm getting this particular message as error in BE.

```
json: cannot unmarshal number -1 into Go struct field ** of type uint8
```

I'm trying out various methods to convert Kotlin's signed ByteArray to unsigned ByteArray, but I'm not able to figure that one out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Bytes are eight bits nothing more. If they are set or not is irrelevant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968476/json-unmarshal-integer-field-into-a-string